# AVR's and DC Motors\Servos

Tags: microcontroller, avr, dc-motor, h-bridge, servo

I've been browsing around looking for some information on motors\servos and AVR's (my MCU of choice). Motors\servos are in my gray area, meaning I'm still not too into them, but I could do something with them if a job arose.

What I want to do is design a little "plate", if you will, that I can use for one of two things:

1. I have a bandsaw and could really use a device that will feed and saw things for me. So an X\Y axis device that I can either control position manually, or automatically with a preset that includes size information on what I'm sawing.
2. I also have a Dremel Press I use for my PCB's. Although I have a great eye and hit my mark perfectly 80-90%+ of the time, automating it would be fantastic. So I would put my PCB on the "plate", and the AVR would position the board at pre-programmed coordinates from like Eagle. And then another motor\servo\solenoid\something would pull the lever and drill the hole; so on and so forth.

The software aspect is no problem for me. So in the purest, most basic form, basically I just need to know the easiest\smartest\best way to use two motors to position an object on an X\Y plane using an AVR (I saw a bit about PWM, but it doesn't seem exact enough to me; maybe I'm missing something). What's the best way to determine distance per revolution with both DC and servo motors?

Thank you all, once again

Answer (score 2):

Check out...

https://acidbourbon.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/semi-automated-drill-press-table-for-pcb-manufacture/

[image]

He used an ATMEGA AVR to control motors connected an X/Y table for positing PCB boards under a drill press. I think very similar to what you are trying to do. His motor circuits and software should give you a great start on your projects.

Comment: A great way to get started with this stuff is to use an Arduino (is actually just an ATMEGA AVR) with the [AdaFruit Motor Shield](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1438">) and a couple of [stepper motors](https://www.adafruit.com/products/324). You can have something working in a few minutes!

Comment: I have a home made Arduino that I use. And I make my own shields and boards, so I'll take a look at this and put something together. The only thing I don't have is steppers. I have some Radioshack servos (they're going out of business here, so everything was like 80% off), and SparkFun DC motors. But thanks.

So do you have a recommended way of finding distance per revolution?